# Python crawl wechat views and likes

Tags: python

I want to know how to crawl the WeChat subscriptions article's views and  likes .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jls7y.jpg)

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried and where you're stuck with the problem. StackOverflow is not for providing the solution to your whole problem, it is about help you navigate through your own solution when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+web+crawling&t=ffab&atb=v169-1&ia=web

Read that for creating a web crawler. After that, you need to use their API. If they don't have an open API with documentation, then go to the site that you want to crawl and go to inspect element. Open the network tab and refresh the page. Find the get request that the site is using for the data you want, and try to make sense of it and apply it to your web crawler. Good luck.